# div Relative Without a Specific Height

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I add some content after a div relative without a specific height?

```css
#team-image-contenitor {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#team-image-contenitor img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#team-image-contenitor img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-column staff-details">
  <div id="team-image-contenitor">
    <img class="bottom" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" alt="">
    <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2" alt="">
  </div>
  <h3>
    title<br>
    title title
  </h3>
  <div class="bio_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacinia dui sit amet sem porta pellentesque. Suspendisse vitae vestibulum augue. Pellentesque nec dignissim sem. Donec vitae eleifend leo. Vivamus euismod augue ut maximus consectetur. Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec feugiat urna, nec euismod magna. Proin tempor risus in tempor mollis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacinia dui sit amet sem porta pellentesque. Suspendisse
    vitae vestibulum augue. Pellentesque nec dignissim sem. Donec vitae eleifend leo. Vivamus euismod augue ut maximus consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec feugiat urna, nec euismod magna. Proin tempor risus
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like that this text will appear after the div.

Comment: Remove `position:absolute;` from `#team-image-contenitor img`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `position: absolute;`, that takes your element out of the document's regular flow, so there's no way for the text to have any positional-relationship with it

In that case, you can use `Jquery` to get the `height` of the image then use the height of the image to become the `margin-top` of the content to avoid overlapping..

Comment: Great output @mattia.. you nailed it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: absolute` for the images to `position: relative`. Easy does it... If this is not what you mean, you should try to explain better ;)

Checkout [the revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/no2ghsbr/1/)

Comment: this doesn't make the effect on hover `img` desire from OP

Comment: i need the position absolute for the animation on rollover of the image.
i would like to keep the animation, and add the text bottom the image (image animation).